# What is the closed form expression for this?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

Let $r_1...r_k$ be the $k$ roots unity or solutions to the expression $x^k = 1$

What is the expression:

$$\frac{1}{x^{k-1}}\frac{1}{\Gamma(-xr_1)}\frac{1}{\Gamma(-xr_2)}\ldots\frac{1}{\Gamma(-xr_k)}$$

equal to?

For the case of $k = 2$:

$$\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\Gamma(-x)}\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)}= \frac{-\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}$$

Comment: It really helps readaability if you format this using MathJax (see FAQ at top right). Regards